# JavaScript - Can I push new structures into an array with a property modified in a for cycle?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I have a problem coding in Javascript that maybe is small but it's making me waste lot of time. All I wanna do is to create a data-structure called "settore" that contains an array of objects "fila" (composed by another list of objects,...). The code i made is:

```
    var settore = {"numero":1, "lista_file":[]};
    var fila = {"lettera": 'A', "lista_posti" : []}; 
    var n_posto = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        var posto = {"numero": ++n_posto, "handicap": false, "vip": false, "occupato": false};
        fila.lista_posti[fila.lista_posti.length] = posto;
    }
    for(var j=0; j<15; j++) {
        settore.lista_file.push(fila);
        fila.lettera = String.fromCharCode(fila.lettera.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    }
    console.log(settore);
```

What that I expected to find within the object "settore" was a list of objects "fila" in which every object has the property "lettera" modified (A, B, C, ect...). Unfortunately with console.log(settore) was:

[console.log(settore)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zep85.png)

and every "lettera" value was "P".
Can someone tell why? I hope someone can help me

P.S:I thoughy it could have been a console.log problem of being out of sync, so I tried console.log(JSON.stringify(settore)) but the result was the same;
P.P.S: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Javascript holds references in variables, mot objects, if you do, `var a = 7;` then `var b = a` and you change b's value, then you change a's toom

Comment: ok now I understand, thank you :) any suggestion about what can I do to solve this problem? I cannot simply push a "fresh" fila object because I need that "fila" is filled with "posto" objects

Comment: Create a constructor function for posto. In the loop create a new instance of it. And the same for fila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made constructor functions Fila and Posto. I fixed your loop so that it is correctly nested. Created the counter for the letter outside the loop, otherwise you will always be incrementing the letter 'A' and all letters will be 'B' which is not what you want either.

```
var settore = {
    "numero": 1,
    "lista_file": []
};

var n_posto = 0;
var fila, _fila, poto;
var filaCharCode = "A".charCodeAt(0);

var Fila = function() {
    this.lettera = "A";
    this.lista_posti = [];
}
var Posto = function(numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
    this.handicap = false;
    this.vip = false;
    this.occupato = false;
}

for (var j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
    fila = new Fila();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        posto = new Posto(++n_posto);
        fila.lista_posti[fila.lista_posti.length] = posto;
    }
    settore.lista_file.push(fila);
    if (settore.lista_file.length > 1) {
        _fila = settore.lista_file[settore.lista_file.length - 2];
        fila.lettera = String.fromCharCode(_fila.lettera.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    }
}
console.log(settore);
```

Comment: Thank You so much, using constructors totally solves my problem and it's usefull for a lot of code I have to make yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor to define a type of object, and then make 'new' copies of it.
I tried to keep it as close to your original code as possible so that you could compare the two. If I were going to write similar functionality, it would be a complete rewrite, like what @Hoyen has. 
Basically I added a constructor and made a change to how `lettera` is assigned so that it starts with 'A' and keeps assigning new values.

```
//Define a constructor. This lets you create "new" instances of this type of object.
//This is as close as ECMAScript (version < 6) gets to a class
function f(lettera,lista_posti){
    this.lettera=lettera;
    this.lista_posti=lista_posti;
}

var settore = {"numero":1, "lista_file":[]};

//Make a new instance of an 'f' object and save it in a variable named 'fila'.
var fila = new f('A', []);
var n_posto = 0;
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var posto = {"numero": ++n_posto, "handicap": false, "vip": false, "occupato": false};
    fila.lista_posti[fila.lista_posti.length] = posto;
}
for(var j=0; j<15; j++) {
    var lettera = String.fromCharCode(fila.lettera.charCodeAt(0)+j);
    //Make a new object of type 'f' that has a new lettera (using 'var'
    // gets us a new one on each iteration of 'for') and a duplicate
    // reference to lista_posti:
    var newFila = new f(lettera,fila.lista_posti)
    settore.lista_file.push(newFila);
}
console.log(settore);
```

Comment: sorry I accidentally editted your post. You can reject it.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer :)